# "Ability of" or "Ability on"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Just a quick question, do I say "I want to develop my abilities **on** English and mathematics" or "I want to develop my abilities **of** English and mathematics"? Alternatives are also welcome.

Comment: I would usually say "methematical abilities".  Looking at the https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ability the usual construction would be "ability of someone to perform something".

Comment: Thanks, but what if the noun following "ability" can't be made into an adjective or if there are multiple nouns? Example in the edited post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ability in** [OED](http://www.oed.com/search?f_0=Full%20Text&pageSize=20&q_0=ability%20in&scope=ENTRY&type=dictionarysearch)

As in:

... depends on deficiency of **ability in** the opposer—deficiency of ...

... depends on deficiency of **ability in** the opposer.

... with **ability in** many departments.

Your sentence, modified:

"I want to develop my abilities in English and mathematics"

Comment: 2006   Prince George (Brit. Columbia) Citizen (Nexis) 2 Feb. 4   Justice Gomery will call for..the defined _ability in law_ to punish those who break the rules. [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/313?rskey=JoDCyP&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid) (Section 7).